# Spring @ContextConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit4

I am running the next test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })
public class FloorServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private FloorService floorService;

    @Test
    public void testFloorService() {

        floorService.findById((long)1);

    }
}
```

With the file `applicationContext.xml` under the folder `/APP/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/`

But it seems not to Autowire correctly the bean:

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.confloorapp.services.FloorServiceTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.confloorapp.services.FloorService com.confloorapp.services.FloorServiceTest.floorService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.confloorapp.services.FloorService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Post that application context?

Comment: Could you please post your ApplicationContext file.

Try `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");`
within your class, that might work

Comment: Can you try with : @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/applicationContext.xml" })

Answer (score 18):

Try

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })
```

Honestly I would step away from the xml and go this route.
Change

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })
```

to

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { FloorServiceTestConfig.class })
```

And create the about class

```
@Configuration
public class FloorServiceTestConfig
{
    @Bean
    public FloorService floorService()
    {
          return new FloorService();
    }
}
```

This way when you need to mock your beans for class you're not testing it looks like below

```
@Configuration
public class FloorServiceTestConfig
{
    @Bean
    public FloorService floorService()
    {
          return Mockito.mock(FloorService.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })  doen not worked :-(

Answer (score 1):

The idea of `@Configuration` given above works nice. But for that you have to annotate your classes with `@Configuration`.
This is not a nice idea when it comes to testing offline i.e when in your organisation test cases are not executed at built time.
In that case going by 
`@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })` will be a nice idea.

For using this method, take care of the following:

1. Check your classpath in `.classpath` file of your project.
2. If you cannot write the path of `applicationContext` relative to classpath.

You can have one more file as `applicationContextTest` folder kept in your test case folder and then one can use
`@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContextTest.xml"})`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
```

Another hint, I see that you use your production `applicationContext.xml` in your test environment, IMHO it's not a good practice, try use a specific one for testing like `applicationContext-test.xml`, so you can play with your test context without hurting your production environment.