# inject bean with real parameters with mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-test

I'm trying to write a unit test case with mockito and I want to inject a bean with real parameters not mocked ones.

That bean has some string values that read from a .properties file.

```
@Component
public class SomeParameters {

    @Value("${use.queue}")
    private String useQueue;

 }

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private A a;

    @Autowired
    private SomeParameters someParameters;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        if(someParameters.getUseQueue==true){
            //do something
        }else{
            /bla bla
        }
    }
```

my main objective is to run a test case with real scenarios. I don't want to use mock values.

I was able to inject bean with real parameters in this way. But this is the unit test case, not an integration test. So I should not give applicationContext. Can you guide me how can handle this situation?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContextTest.xml"})
public class ServiceTest {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a **spring-context** then you should create a configuration (via xml or java config) for your test and declare only the beans that you require. [For Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618039/spring-contextconfiguration)

For setting properties just declare `@TestPropertiesSource("use.queue=someValue")` otherwise you need to read value from test resources.

PS. also check [@MockBean and @SpyBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999517/what-is-difference-between-spybean-and-mockbean-in-mockito) especially `@SpyBean`

Comment: I suppose I will use spring-context. There is no way to use a bean (not mocked) without spring-context. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use real properties, then load the property file using Properties object and mock the value by getting from Properties object.